# Getting jQuery Validation plug-in to work with requirejs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I've created a form on WordPress-powered site. It's currently using RequireJS to add two buttons to a page element, but I'd also like Require to control some things in the jQuery Validation plug-in.  The adding of the buttons work fine, but sadly, the validation is not working.

The form looks like this in the HTML:

```
  <form id="contact" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset id="contact-form-fields">
      <p>
        <label for="form_name" class="form-titles">Name</label>
        <input name="form_name" id="form_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" aria-required="true" class="required"> 
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="form_email" class="form-titles">Email</label>
        <input name="form_email" id="form_email" type="text" placeholder="Email" aria-required="true" value="">  
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="msg_text" class="form-titles">Email</label>
        <textarea tabindex="-8" rows="10" placeholder="Type your awesome message here." class="placeholder" name="msg_text" id="msg_text" aria-required="true" class="required"></textarea>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" class="button">
  </form>
```

RequireJS is attached to the page like this:

```
<script data-main="http://livetest.kaidez.com/wp-content/themes/kaidez-2012/js/config.js" src="http://livetest.kaidez.com/wp-content/themes/kaidez-2012/js/require-jquery.js"></script>
```

The above-mentioned config.js file looks like this:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "http://livetest.kaidez.com/wp-content/themes/kaidez-2012/js",

  deps: ['scripts'],

  paths: {
    jquery: "jquery",
    jqueryValidate: "jquery-validate.min" 
  },

  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: "jquery"
    },
    jqueryValidate: {
      deps: ["jquery"]
    }
  }
});
```

config.js says it has a dependency called scripts.js, which looks like this:

```
// code that adds buttons to the page
require(['jquery'], function ($) {

  var header = document.getElementById("masthead"),
    $navMenu = $("#site-navigation-list"),
    $searchBox = $("#searchform"),
    menuButton = document.createElement("div"),
    searchButton = document.createElement("div"),
    showMenus;

  $(menuButton).attr("id", "menu");
  $(searchButton).attr("id", "search");

  header.appendChild(searchButton);
  header.appendChild(menuButton);

  showMenus = function(btn,el) {
    $(btn).click(function() {
      if (el.is(":visible") ) {
        el.slideUp({
          complete:function(){
            $(this).css("display","");
          }
        });
       } else {
         el.slideDown();
       }
    });
  };

  showMenus(menuButton, $navMenu);
  showMenus(searchButton, $searchBox);

});

//code that controls jQuery Validate
require(["jquery", "jqueryValidate"], function($, jqueryValidate) {
  $("#contact").validate({
    rules: {
      form_email: {
        required: true,
        number: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Looking at other posted questions, jsFiddles, etc and I can't seem to find an answer.  I think my error is in my RequireJS settings but I'm not sure. Working dev environment code is [here](http://livetest.kaidez.com/). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I've found an answer to my own question. The TL;DR answer is:

> *RequireJS can be added to work in WordPress but if you install jQuery-dependent plugins via WP-Admin, there's a VERY good chance that you'll load jQuery core a second time, which is not good.*

The long answer...here we go:

I was trying to use two RequireJS modules to manage form validation with some help from the [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin (the above-mention code to add buttons doesn't matter). I got this to work with the following code:

The contact form looks like this in the HTML:

```
<p id="success-msg" style="display:none">Your message has been sent successfully.</p>
<!-- The tag above appears if the form goes through-->
  <form id="contact" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="left">
        <input name="form_name" id="form_name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name"> 
      </div>
      <div>
        <input name="form_email" id="form_email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" class="required email">  
      </div>
      <textarea tabindex="-8" rows="10" placeholder="Type your awesome message here." class="placeholder" name="msg_text" id="msg_text" ></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" class="button">
  </form>
```

RequireJS is referenced in the HTML like this:

```
// both require.js and config.js are stored in a directory called 'js' in a child theme
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/require.js" data-main="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/config.js"></script>
```

config.js looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/yourTheme/js",

  deps: ["form"], // lists 'form.js' as a dependency, where our form code will be

  paths: {
    /*
     * Referencing the 'wp-includes/js/'
     * directory in WP. jQuery was pre-installed 
     * but Validation was manually added.
     */
    jquery: "http://yourdomain.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery",
    val: "http://yourdomain.com/wp-includes/js/validate"
  },

  shim: { 
  jquery: {
    exports: 'jquery'
  },
  val: {
    deps: ['jquery'],
    exports: 'jquery'
  }
},

  waitSeconds: 20
});
```

The above-mentioned form.js file looks like this:

```
define("form", ["jquery", "val"], function($) {

$("#contact").submit(function(event) {
  var name = $("#form_name").val();
  var email = $("#form_email").val();
  var text = $("#msg_text").val();
  var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + text;

  event.preventDefault();

    if($("#contact").valid()){
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/yourTheme/email.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(){
        $("#contact").fadeOut(100);
        $('#success-msg').fadeIn(100);
      }
    });

    return false;
    }
  });
});
```

And just for clarity, the PHP that sends out an email after a successful form submission (email.php) looks like this.

```
<?php

if($_POST){
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $text=$_POST['text'];

  //send email
  mail("your@email.com", "your subject",
  $text, "From:" . $email);
}

?>
```

The good news is that everything above works as is.  The bad news shows up if you use WordPress to install a jQuery-dependent plugin. Due to the WordPress architecture, plugins like this will automatically install jQuery core unless it's already installed via `functions.php` or some other WP internal method.  Calling jQuery via RequireJS like I did won't stop this.

I tried a lot of different methods to fix this using `wp_deregister_script()`, `wp_enqueue_script()`, etc. but had no luck. This works fine for the personal project I'm working on but it's probably not good for a client project.

There is a WordPress ticket to add AMD functionality to WordPress with the goal of calling different versions of jQuery. (read it [here)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23285). Hopefully this issue will be addressed if there's follow-thru on the ticket.  Until then, I'm pretty sure that this is how it is, for now.